# Родственные слова к омонимам

Tags: омонимы

Подберите родственные слова к данным омонимам. Какой вывод о свойствах омонимов можно сделать на основании полученных вами словообразовательных рядов?

Правильно ли я выполнила задание?

КЛАСС - классовый, деклассированный; КЛАСС - классный, внеклассный.
МИР - мирный, смирный, мирить; МИР - мировой, всемирный.
БРАК - бракосочетание, брачующиеся; БРАК - отбраковать, бракованный.
ВИД - видный, свидание, очевидный; ВИД - подвид, видоизменяемость. 
МЕХ - меховщик, меховой; МЕХ - механический, механика.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Последняя пара неудачна.

МЕХ 1 - меховщик, меховой;

МЕХ 2 - кузнечные мехи. Родственные слова подобрать нельзя, потому что слово не употребляется, непродуктивно в словообразовании: новые слова от него не образуются; отличить от омонима можно с помощью определения кузнечный.

механический, механика, мехколонна не являются омонимами слова мех, это родственные к слову механика, слово заимствованное = техника.